# Incrementing offset of Location and clicking on location

Tags: rascal

I got a problem on clicking locations. The thing I do is creating a AST from a method with the function:

```
getMethodASTEclipse(method, model=projectModel);
```

where method is just an instance of

```
methods(projectModel);
```

When I visit that tree and want to get if statements for example I can call

```
case i: \if(_, _, _):println(i@src);
```

The source will be printed and I can click on it, eclipse will go to the right class with the right if statement. The form is like this:

```
|project://MyProject/src/MyClass.java|(2836,143,<104,1>,<109,2>)
```

But when I get the AST from file with the method:

```
createAstFromFile(class, true);
```

and giving a class instaed of a method or even a file I can also visit it and get the same if statement and print it but the form of it is different and I can't click on it. Why not ?

The form of it looks like this:

```
|java+class:///MyClass/src/MyClass|(17938,1105,<544,4>,<570,5>)
```

What I also notice is that the offsets are incrementing heavily after each location is printed.

How can I make it clickable to the right location? I think it has to do something with the offset and the form of the location. I tried to use the method:

```
resolveJava(loc l);
```

from the Registry class but that didn't work either and tried to look up at declarations for the |loc definition but that wasn't there either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the locations aren't clickable is because they cannot be resolved. The problem is that `createAstFromFile(_,_)` was only intended to be used with locations that have either `project` or `file` schemes.

For now, you can get the physical location from the `declarations` annotation in the model and use that to create the AST.

We'll look into making it so that it is possible to use locations with other schemes as well.